# Why should the cubic equation in volume, obtained from Van Der Waals equation of state, have equal roots at the critical point?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

The video [Edmerls —
Derive Equation for Critical Constants in terms of Vander Waal's Constants. | Physical Chemistry](https://youtu.be/qyBK4Gio80w) (YouTube) provides a derivation of the relationship between the van der Waals constants and the critical pressure, temperature, and volume.

It involves rearranging the van der Waals equation to form a cubic equation in the volume $V$ and comparing it to $(V - V_\mathrm{crit})^3 = 0$, where $V_\mathrm{crit}$ is the critical volume.

Why does the equation need to have equal roots? And can it also have equal roots for other fixed values of pressure and temperature (apart from the critical pressure and temperature)?

Comment: Do you know why the original  van der Waals equation has 2 equal real roots at and only at the critical point?

Comment: I don't, could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: 1/ Converging 2 V values ( V_gas and V_liquid at given T,p) to the single V value 2/ Zero 1st and 2nd derivative dp/dV and d2p/dV^2 at T_c,p_c  3/ For T > T_c, function p=f(V) is monotonous = 1 root.   For T < T_c,  p=f(V) has the local maximu and minimum with 3 roots (the particular shape of the functions has just limited, physical interpretation here )